# integrate over the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have a stochastic process $dX(t)=k[A-Y(t)]f(t)dt$, where $Y(t)$ is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, and satisfies: $dY(t)=k[A-Y(t)]dt+\sigma dW(t)$ and $Y(0)=0$. $f(t)=0$ for $t<\tau$ and $f(t)=1$ for $t\geq\tau$. Now I want to solve for $X(t)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X(t))$, $\mathbb{V}(X(t))$.

I could plug in $Y(t)=A(1-e^{-kt})+\sigma\int_0^t e^{-k(t-s)}dW_s$, but how shall I proceed? I am new to SDE, and any help is highly appreciated!
(I find this question related to [How to solve system of stochastic differential equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050770/how-to-solve-system-of-stochastic-differential-equations))

EDIT:

I found this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143245/distribution-of-integral-of-exponential-of-wiener-process. Why does this hold? $\sigma e^{as}\int_0^s e^{-as}dW_s=\beta W_s$ where $\beta^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{2a}(1-e^{-2as})$? Actually I cannot obtain the right formula of variance for the OU process based on this equation.

Assuming this is correct, my attempt for $\tau=0$: (Let me know if anything is wrong)

$Y(t)=A(1-e^{-kt})+\beta(t)W(t)$ where $(\beta(t))^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{2k}(1-e^{-2kt})$. So $dX(t)=(kAe^{-kt}-k\beta(t) W_t)dt$. Thus $\mathbb{E}(X(T))=\int_0^T kAe^{-kt}dt$.

I am still confused in obtaining $\mathbb{V}(X(t))$, and thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is $\tau$ a random variable or a deterministic constant? What about $A$...?

Comment: $\tau$ and $A$ are constants. Thanks! @saz